# There is data in one column like this 1/year and 1/3year in that I want a output like 1 and 1/3 respectively

Tags: sql

In sql server, There is data in one column like this 1/year and 1/3year in that I want a output like 1 and 1/3 respectively

1.

| original_column |
| --- |
| 1year |
| 3year |
| 1/4 years |
| 1/5 Month |

Output will be:

| Numbers | Characters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | year |
| 3 | year |
| 1/4 | years |
| 1/5 | Month |

```
Select SUBSTRING(original_column, 1, CHARINDEX('/', original_column) - 1)as numbers,
    SUBSTRING(original_column, CHARINDEX('/', original_column) + 1, LEN(original_column)) as characters from table_A;
```

Comment: Why does your query code stop in the middle? What is your exact question?

Comment: It seems that both your columns should be character-based.

Comment: if you want column output, why you using UPDATE statement. you can use this in the select statement too ?

Comment: also do you really have spaces in between in some data ?

Comment: Yes it's having a space and I also try select query which I have a recently updated

Comment: -- PM 77-1 yes both are the character but I want a output like this which I have a mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PATINDEX` for locating the position of the first alpha in each string.

```
select 
 original_column, 
 substring(original_column, 1, patindex('%[^0123456789/ ]%', original_column) - 1) as numbers, 
 right(original_column, len(original_column) - patindex('%[^0123456789/ ]%', original_column) + 1) as characters
from table1
```

| original_column | numbers | characters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1year | 1 | year |
| 3year | 3 | year |
| 1/4 years | 1/4 | years |
| 1/5Month | 1/5 | Month |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/thwLQSrv)

Comment: In number column I get 1/ and 3/

Comment: I'm using your exact sample data, so not sure why you would get that. The only change I made was I removed a space between 1/5 and Month in that 4th row just to get more variety in your data.

Comment: Thank you for this query. I use the subquery in it and I use a case condition with right function and I replace the last slash using it.